# How to assign values from an object to properties in an array, conditionally

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, arrays

I need to assign values from an array of objects, to an object, with different keys.

In the JavaScript app, I'm working with, I get an array of objects returned similar to below:

```
urlArrayOfObjects = [ 

    {url: 'https://amazon.co.uk', country: 'uk'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.com', country: 'usa'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.ca', country: 'canada'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.es', country: 'spain'}
]
```

The object is the something like the following:

```
urlTables = {
    short_url_id: "",
    uk_url: "",
    usa_url: "",
    canada_url: "",
    irland_url: "",
    spain_url: "",
    germany_url: "",
    default_country: "",
    default_url: "",
    customer_id: ""
}
```

I need to extract values from **urlArrayOfObjects** and insert them into the appropriate properties in the **urlTables** (And if there are no values, if should default to **null**

For e.g. in the above case, **urlTables** should look like the following after I'm done with it:

```
urlTables = {
    short_url_id: null,
    uk_url: "https://amazon.co.uk",
    usa_url: "https://amazon.com",
    canada_url: "https://amazon.ca",
    irland_url: null,
    spain_url: "https://amazon.es",
    germany_url: null,
    default_country: null,
    default_url: null,
    customer_id: null}
```

What is the best way of going about achieving this?
Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: By the way, Ireland is spelled with an "e" after the "r", not Irland :). Also added an answer for you below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an area where JavaScript, as compared to a strongly typed language really shines. You can simply fetch the values and use them as field names.

For example:

`urlTables[urlArrayOfObjects[0].country + "_url"] = urlArrayOfObjects[0].url;`

The idea is the same for everything else so you just need to loop.

Here's an example loop:

```
for(var item of urlArrayOfObjects){
    urlTables[item.country + "_url"] = item.url;
}
```

Comment: Oh this is amazing. And simple! Thanks a lot! I don't understand reduce method much.. so this one is more understandable to me :D

Answer (score 2):

I would do it like this:

```js
let urlArrayOfObjects = [ 

    {url: 'https://amazon.co.uk', country: 'uk'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.com', country: 'usa'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.ca', country: 'canada'},
    {url: 'https://amazon.es', country: 'spain'}
]

let urlTables = {
    short_url_id: null,
    uk_url: null,
    usa_url: null,
    canada_url: null,
    irland_url: null,
    spain_url: null,
    germany_url: null,
    default_country: null,
    default_url: null,
    customer_id: null
}


console.log(
    urlArrayOfObjects.reduce((carry, current) => {
        return {
            ...carry,
            [current.country + '_url']: current.url
        }
    }, urlTables)
);
```

Comment: Oh wow this looks very clean! Thank you so much! It works great. But I don't understand Reduce much , so I'm Googling some of the syntax :D